# Is there a way to resize Safari windows while in full screen mode on Safari 6 or higher?

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen

When full screen mode was first introduced the window in Safari was resizable but it seems that it has been disabled or at least disabled by default. Is there a way to bring back this functionality?

http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/04/resize-safari-windows-while-in-full-screen-mode/

Comment: Steve, do you mean by not option-clicking Safari's maximize button?  When I do that, I can reduce the width of Safari to almost nothing.  Are you looking for something different than that?

Comment: @fbara What version of Safari are you running? I want to stay in full screen mode like what was possible in Lion as the article describes.

Comment: Safari 9.1.  It's hard to tell from the screenshot in that article and I don't have Lion so I can't try it out.  As an example, after I option-click the maximize button, grab the bottom right corner of Safari and drag it to the left, hiding all the questions on the right side of this page.  Is this what you're looking for?  Sorry for not completely understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Safari Responsive Design Mode

This is more of a work around than a solution. Safari's Responsive Design Mode new to El Capitan and allows you to set the width of a website while in full screen mode. It is enabled through Safari's developer mode.